# Controller doesn't see function

Tags: angularjs

This is my services.js

```
(function () {   
var app = angular.module('crmService', []);

app.factory('timeline', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var _addTimelineEvent = function (clientId, eventData) {
            callback = callback || function () {};

            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/simple_crm/web/api.php/client/' + clientId + '/timeline',
                data: eventData
            });
        };

        return {
            addTimelineEvent: _addTimelineEvent
        };
    }]);
})();
```

And this is my controller:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
            .when('/clients', {
                controller: 'ClientsListCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/clients-list.html'
            })
            .when('/clients/:clientId', {
                controller: 'ClientDetailCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/client-details.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/clients'
            });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

```
app.controller('ClientDetailCtrl', ['$scope', 'clients', 'users', 'sectors', '$routeParams', '$timeout', 'timeline',
    function ($scope, clients, users, sectors, $routeParams, $timeout, timeline) {

        $scope.client = {};
        $scope.timeline = []; 
        $scope.timelineEvent = {};
        $scope.eventTypes = timeline.getEventsType();

        $scope.saveClientData = function () {
            if ($scope.clientForm.$invalid)
                return;

            clients.updateClient($scope.client.id, $scope.client)
                    .then(
                            function () {
                                //messeges to user
                            },
                            function (error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                    );
        };

        $scope.addEvent = function () {

            if ($scope.eventForm.$invalid)
                return;

            timeline.addTimelineEvent($scope.client.id, $scope.timelineEvent)
                    .then(
                            function () {
                                //messeges to user

                            },
                            function (error){
                                console.log(error);
                            });

        };

    }]);
})();
```

And I get an error:

> TypeError timeline.addTimelineEvent is not a function

I am not able to understand why the function that is above works fine but timeline.addTimelineEvent, which is virtually identical, reports an error.
Any advice?

I added all code for better view :

[Full code](http://plnkr.co/edit/2iUpb5UrFsRbCTT6E2xf?p=preview)

The timeline function is located at the end of the app file

Comment: Could you possibly update a more full example to jsfiddle or something a like? And be more specific about which function does work for you?

Comment: What about using `$scope.timeline.addTimelineEvent` ?

Comment: Strange! Can you reproduce [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3yiqY2WfUJcMuOuwQSXd?p=preview), What I tried is working fine.

Comment: can you show us the html as well? I am guessing the problem is in the router

Comment: I found a solution.
There was a name conflict, it was enough to change the name of the 'factory' timeline to 'time' so that it did not conflict with other variables in controller also change timeline.addTimelineEvent to time.addTimelineEvent
Thank you for trying to help :)